# javax.sound.sampled Clip on linux does not work correctly

Tags: java, linux, audio, javax

I'm working on a cross platform java project, which consists to reproduce a Audio Input Stream. Here a piece of code as example:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();
```

The issue is that if i run my project on macOS and Windows all is working perfectly, on linux I get no exceptions or errors but I can hear a portion of the audio, and it reproduce the same portion systematically. Why? Can you help me please?

My testing linux OS specs:
kernel 4.8.0-22-generic
Ubuntu 16.10
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

Comment: Maybe the issue is with your drivers.

Comment: Look at the docs for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html and see what kind of information you can get for your MixerInfo.  You may need JMF or OpenAL.

Comment: @jnbbender i tried on another machine, not virtual one and I got the same issue